# CakePHP3 HABTM erro ao inserir dados na tabela

Tags: sql-insert, cakephp-3, habtm

Estou com o erro Cannot insert row in "addresses_companies" table, it has no primary key na minha aplicação, após inserir uma empresa e preencher os dados de endereço e selecionar uma empresa aparece o erro citado acima.

Segue código:

**AddressesController.php**

```
public function add()
{
    $address = $this->Addresses->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $address = $this->Addresses->patchEntity($address, $this->request->data, ['associated' => ['Companies']]);
        if ($this->Addresses->save($address)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The address has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The address could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $companies = $this->Addresses->Companies->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('address', 'companies'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['address']);
}
```

**Address**

```
use Cake\ORM\Entity;

/**
 * Address Entity.
 */
class Address extends Entity
{

/**
 * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
 *
 * @var array
 */
   protected $_accessible = [
    'CEP' => true,
    'ENDERECO' => true,
    'BAIRRO' => true,
    'CIDADE' => true,
    'ESTADO' => true,
    'UF' => true,
    'companies' => true,
    'addresses_companies' => true,
   ];
}
```

**AddressesTable**

```
use App\Model\Entity\Address;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
* Addresses Model
*
* @property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsToMany $Companies
*/
class AddressesTable extends Table
{

/**
 * Initialize method
 *
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 * @return void
 */
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('addresses');
    $this->displayField('ID');
    $this->primaryKey('ID');
    $this->belongsToMany('Companies', [
        'foreignKey' => 'address_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'company_id',
        'joinTable' => 'addresses_companies',
        'dependent' => true
    ]);
}

/**
 * Default validation rules.
 *
 * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
 * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
 */
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->add('ID', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
        ->allowEmpty('ID', 'create');

    $validator
        ->add('CEP', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
        ->requirePresence('CEP', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('CEP');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('ENDERECO', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('ENDERECO');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('BAIRRO', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('BAIRRO');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('CIDADE', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('CIDADE');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('ESTADO', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('ESTADO');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('UF', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('UF');

    return $validator;
}
}
```

**add.ctp**

```
<div class="addresses form large-10 medium-9 columns">
<?= $this->Form->create($address) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Address') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('CEP');
        echo $this->Form->input('ENDERECO');
        echo $this->Form->input('BAIRRO');
        echo $this->Form->input('CIDADE');
        echo $this->Form->input('ESTADO');
        echo $this->Form->input('UF');
        echo $this->Form->input('companies._ids', ['options' => $companies]);
    ?>
    </fieldset>
       <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
       <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Quero entender o que está faltando, pois não acho exemplos na internet e o encontrado no site do CakePHP não me ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema adicionando elas como primary key, porém agora me apareceu a seguinte frase.

Cannot insert row, some of the primary key values are missing. Got (, )

Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Grato